# Where are civil fine amounts for vehicle traffic law violations documented?

Tags: data-request, state, traffic, legal, spending

We are interested in civil fine amounts for all vehicle traffic law violations for all states and jurisdictions.

Does anyone know the website or open data portal that contains this information?

It appears that in New York State the Department of Motor Vehicle Referees (this is the title of the person that makes the decision at the Traffic Violations Bureau (TVB) hearings) seem to have a list of civil fine amounts (both minimum and, I assume, maximum)  All this information should be public and also does anyone know the process on how the civil fines (minimum and maximum) are determined.  That also should be a public process.

I've called our New York State Department of Motor Vehicle Data Services and FOIL department and they very politely told me that they are not sure if this data exists and I would have to pay the FOIL search fee and the fee per page for this information.  That seems odd for such general information that should be publicly available in our DMV website and open data sites.

In the meantime, I have uploaded all the NYS traffic tickets from 2008 to 2012 here: http://bit.ly/nystickets The data is from the very limited function NYS open data site.

If you know SQL then, read carefully. I've placed the raw data here: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/personal-real-estate:nys.traffic_tickets?pli=1

You can query all the data yourself.

Here's one interesting query result:

**The top ten actual traffic violations:**

```
count   violation_charged_code  violation_description
1898178 1180D   SPEED IN ZONE
976955  1225C2A IMPRPR CELLPHONE USE
788251  1180B   SPEED OVER 55 ZONE
759342  306B    UNINSPECTED MOTOR VEHICLE
752639  1110A   DISOB TRAFFIC DEVICE
671633  5091    UNLICENSED OPERATOR
667455  1229C3A NO SEAT BELT DRIVER
507210  37512A2 TINTED GLASS
480491  1225C2A OPERATING MV MOBILE PHONE
471609  1229C3  NO SEAT BELT ADULT
```

There are even bicycle/skater specific law but apparently they do not have to be used.  It is apparently at the discretion of a police officer what violation they wish to place on the ticket.  Is this the [equal protection of the laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_Protection_Clause)?

```
count   violation_charged_code  violation_description
9636    1231    RULES ROAD VIO BICY
2532    37524A  OPER MV/MC/BIC W/MORE 1 EARPHONE
2357    1236B   NO BELL/SIG DEV BICY
1412    1236A   NO/INADEQUATE LIGHTS-BICYCLE
1169    1236B   NO BELL OR SIGNAL DEVICE ON BICYCLE
768     1234A   FAILURE TO KEEP RIGHT-BICYCLE
228     1232A   IMPROPER OPERATION OF BICYCLE
227     1234C   FAILURE TO STOP WHEN ENTERING ROAD/BICYCLE
155     18231A  UNAUTHORIZED USE OF RESTRICTED VEH ON PKWY-BICYCLE
148     1236C   NO/INADEQUATE BRAKES-BICYCLE
143     1236E   NO/IMPROPER REFLECTOR-BICYCLE
95      1236D   NO REFLECTOR WHEEL/BICYCLE
90      1238    NO CHILD BICYCLE HELMET
74      1229AB  BIC/PUSHCART/ANIMAL DRWN VEH ON EXPRESSWAY
60      1232B   TOO MANY RIDERS - BICYCLE
50      1234B   MORE THAN TWO ABREAST-BICYCLE
31      1122-A  FAILED TO SAFELY PASS A BICYCLE
30      1235    CARRYING OBSTRUCTIVE ARTICLES ON BICYCLES
6       1230A   PERMITTED VIO OF ARTICLE 34/OPER OF BICYCLES
3       1122AU  UNSAFE PASS BICYCLE
```

**Unusual actual traffic violations:**

```
1   398D2   FLD TO MAKE WRITTEN ESTIMATE/CHARGED EXCESS
1   12221B  NO OPER-RACKS INSEC
1   5072JL  FLD EXHB LIC JR <=60
1   2130A5  PROD/MANUFCTURE/POSESS DEV TO REPRODUCE TITLE CERT
1   509L2B  PERMIT/REQ OPER/REMAIN ON DUTY INTOX
1   2129B   FAILED TO REPORT RECOVERY VEH
1   1203D2  PARKED ON HIGHWAY FOR REPAIR
1   10311   EMER LIGHT EQUIP-TWY
1   14F4C   OPERATING A VEHICLE OUT OF SERVICE
1   415A10B FLD/KEEP IMPROPER RECORDS SCRAP COL
1   10736   FLD USE DESG LA-TBTA
1   1228    RIDING IN HOUSE TRLR
1   509L1C  POSSESS ALCOHOL ON DUTY OPERATING BUS
1   1022    PROH LIQOR/INTOX BEV
1   17055   NONE
```

Amazing!!! RIDING IN HOUSE TRLR is specifically prohibited by law???

Why not have a law specifically prohibiting RIDING IN ELEVATOR, RIDING IN OUTDOOR TOILET, RIDING RECKLESSLY INTO OUTER SPACE AND TO THE MOON, etc. etc. etc.

Here is a FOIL request to the New York State Department of Motor Vehicle

If you are a non profit organization or public representative, please comment here or contact us we'd like to form an organization to make law and civil fines more transparent and equal and logical.

> Please provide in CSV all civil fine amounts (both minimum and maximum) for all New York
>   State (NYS) Vehicle Traffic Law (VTL) violations for all jurisdictions
>   in New York State.

```
The header row should be: 
Jurisdiction, VTLnumber, minfine, maxfine, dateenacted, active 

Example Format of Data Expected:
NYC, VTL1231, 0, 50, 2000-01-01, Y
```

Comment: This feels like 2 different questions. Can you split them up?

Comment: Thanks @rcackerman but the other question(s) would probably not be a simple question.  Why is the our laws NOT well organized and why is our laws written in a hodge podge of patch after patch.  Like any good software project, sometimes there comes a time for a re-write/re-design  And why is our law not available for download?  And why is our law (especially traffic law) not documented in official videos and charts and pictures?  Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: This comes across as a bit of a rant. Also, you'd probably want to clarify if you're looking for all states, or just states in one country (e.g. USA).

Comment: Yes all states is preferable.